# Use Partial Views between multiple mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have an scenario like, define a template for footer of my website in partial view. I have written the footer template in partial view. This partial view is placed in folder name "Common" in Views.

Now i want to use this footer partial view in another mvc application, because used the same footer template.

How can i refer the partial views in multiple applications, like having the partial views in class library?

Please guide me to go right way.

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: It is better to create one method that will return footer partial view. By using json ajax call you can get the partial from that application.

Comment: @Jayesh: You mean to use custom html helper controls?

Comment: Create one method in Application1. So, when i will call this action method it will return partial view. It doesn't matter if from where i will call this method. try to implement this type of functionality.

Comment: i dont want to call ajax actions. is it possible to call @Html.Partial("/Views/Common/footer.cshtml") in view?